# Using Proxy over Set

Tags: javascript, proxy, set

I'm trying to wrap a JS `Set` in a `Proxy`, and have the following interchange with node REPL

```
> const s = new Set()
undefined
> s.add(1)
Set(1) { 1 }
> const p = new Proxy(s, {})
undefined
> p
Proxy [ Set(1) { 1 }, {} ]
> p.add(1)
Uncaught:
TypeError: Method Set.prototype.add called on incompatible receiver [object Object]
    at Proxy.add (<anonymous>)
```

Is there any way to use `Set` wrapped in a `Proxy`?

PS. I'm assuming this will also be true for other built-ins like Map, WeakMap, etc?

EDIT:
playing around further, `bind`ing a method and setting it on `s` does allow for it to be called without throwing an error.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by using a proxy?

Comment: access control.